# IE7 displays trademark entity as serif within sans-serif font

Tags: css, fonts, internet-explorer-7, html-entities, google-font-api

I have a webpage that uses Google's [Open Sans](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans) font. The webpage also uses an HTML entity for the trademark symbol (`&trade;`).

In Internet Explorer 7, this entity is not displayed using Open Sans, it is displayed in a serif font:

[image: IE7 rendering trademark entity incorrectly]

Here is a short page that reproduces the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700" />
        <!--[if lte IE 8]>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700" />
        <![endif]-->
        <style type="text/css">
        * {
            font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>This is trademarked&trade;</h1>
        <p>This is trademarked&trade;</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Using the entity `&#8482;` results in the same problem, as does using a literal ™, but oddly enough the `&reg;` entity displays correctly.

Is there anyway to get this entity to render either in Open Sans, or if that fails, in a sans-serif font?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem in IE 7 emulation mode of IE 11. However, IE 6 (in a virtual XP machine) exhibits a similar problem: instead of “™” in any font, a small rectangle appears—a typical symptom of lack of glyph. This also happens for some other Windows-1252 characters, such as “š”, but not all.

Comment: I'm not sure IE11's emulation mode is 100% faithful to the problems with IE7. I find it odd that there is a problem with &trade; but not with &reg; as I would've assumed they were treated the same. I've tried changing IE7's encoding to UTF-8, Windows-1252, and ISO-8859-1 but it makes no difference.

Comment: Does this issue appear in more modern versions of Internet Explorer?

Comment: Nope. Internet Explorer 8 and upwards work as expected. Unfortunately the website has to support Internet Explorer 7 and above.

Answer (score 2):

Both Open Sans & Arial don't have entities, so your browser will default to a system font for them. Try adding some alternative system fonts in your lineup:

```
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Calibri, Arial Unicode MS, Lucida Sans Unicode, DejaVu Sans, FreeSans, sans-serif;
```